# Drupal Bootstrap theme

Tags: theming, blocks

I have a sidebar block and a content block. I want display both of them as inline. But my Bootstrap theme gives me one section (row) with col-sm-12, how can I create a new row, with a sidebar (col-sm-4) and a content block (col-sm-8).

I have no idea on how to do this. Do I Need a extra module or do I achieve them with settings in my theme?

Comment: You can always modify your templates. Whether a page, a node page, a block, etc. There is generally a way to update those to your convenience. Can you give us more details about what are you trying to achieve? Are those blocks in a page? view?

Comment: These blocks are in a page. But he created one section with 'col-sm-12'. I want create a new row for my sidebar and content block.

Comment: Most themes have a section for sidebar. Yours should have one too. You can have a look at the block section (admin/structure/block). 

Once you add your block there and one in your content section, you could manually modify your page.tpl.php template (in your theme directory) and add those classes yourself.

Comment: @dp2013, Boostrap comes with 'Primary', 'Secondary' and 'Content' sections by default.  When you check admin/structure/block do you see them?  The 'Primary' and 'Secondary' sections are the two blocks on the left and right respectively.